# Adding multiple items to a PHP array in a foreach loop - is there a nicer way?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

**Sample Code**

```
<?php 
    $items = array(
        array(
            'forename' => 'Foo',
            'surname' => 'Bar'
        ),
            array(
            'forename' => 'Bar',
            'surname' => 'Foo'
        )
    );

    $arr = array();
    $i = 0;

    foreach($items as $item){
        $arr[$i]['name'] = $item['forename'];
        $arr[$i]['surname'] = $item['surname'];
        $i++;
    }

    echo "<pre>".print_r($arr, true)."</pre>";
?>
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Foo
            [surname] => Bar
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Bar
            [surname] => Foo
        )
)
```

The result is perfectly acceptable and the code is readable.
My question is: **is there a better / more efficient / prettier way to do this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a massive amount you could do to that code, you could get rid of the need to have an incremental variable (`$i`) by using `foreach($items as $key => $value)` and using `$key` instead of `$i`.

Comment: You don't even need a variable `$i` if you use the `$arr[] = $item ... ` syntax.

Comment: As I'm adding more than one item to an array I need a shared key. Using the method you specified would give me a completely separate array for `name` and `surname` within $arr

Comment: @Sam, true, but see my answer for context of how it would be used.

Answer (score 1):

This is fine and there is not really a better way to do it.  Here is an alternative that is arguably more or less readable:

```
$items = array(
    array(
        'forename' => 'Foo',
        'surname' => 'Bar'
    ),
        array(
        'forename' => 'Bar',
        'surname' => 'Foo'
    )
);

foreach ($items as &$item) {
   $item['name'] = $item['forename'];
   unset($item['forename']);
}
```

Note that this will put the `name` key after `surname` if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you can use something like `array_merge()`, but since you are renaming keys there is nothing straightforward. You could do something like:

```
$keys = array('forename' => 'name', 'surname' => 'surname');
```

And then in your current `foreach` loop have a second `foreach` loop that iterates over that. But to me, that is not any better unless you are doing this same thing many times.

Actually, `array_combine()` might help, although you have to be careful with that to keep ordering:

```
$arr[] = array_combine(array('name', 'surname'), $item);
```

Note: you may need to use `array_values($item)`, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way

```
<?php 
    $items = array(
        array(
            'forename' => 'Foo',
            'surname' => 'Bar'
        ),
            array(
            'forename' => 'Bar',
            'surname' => 'Foo'
        )
    );

    $arr = array();


    foreach($items as $item){
        $arr['name'][] = $item['forename'];
        $arr['surname'][] = $item['surname'];

    }

    echo "<pre>".print_r($arr, true)."</pre>";
?>
```

check the out put http://3v4l.org/v2GhH